# How to make a POST request then reload the list of items in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm using fetch to post an item to my server.

```js
const post = () => {
//..
return fetch(url, requestOptions as RequestInit);
}
```

Then I use this function in a Promise which run when all field is validated.

```js
const onSave = () => {
 form.validateFields().then((values) => {
  post().then((response) => response).then((result) => {
   if (result.status === 200) {
    alert("Add item successful");
    // then I dispatch an action which get all item and put to redux state (I used redux-saga to do it)
    dispatch(anActionFetchListItem);
   }
 })
})
```

So, the problem is my list of items is unstable after adding an item.

The first time I got the alert is add successful but the list of items is not changed. But the second time it's changed and includes the first item I added.

I don't know what is the issue here, I tried to add an alert in Promise, and surely that Item always add successfully. Sometimes see the change, sometimes not.

Thanks!

UPDATE: I found that it's a bug from API, I did it the right way!

Comment: Did you check the response from the server after fetching the new list item?

Comment: @Danny I checked it, it does not include the missing item, but I checked the response status before reloading the list, it must have that item, right?

Comment: Please keep the comments in English, @Danny and Dun.

Answer (score 1):

So you have to check the backend.
Client post > API > backend service (logic) > model connect with Database > return response
It means that if the backend is implemented in the right way, there will be no error when you receive the response with status 200.